# Unable to retrieve updated textbox value php

Tags: php, post, input, textbox, echo

// **RESOLVED**

I found out what was causing this problem - the textboxes were inside a div with display:none .

// -------------------------------------

I have some echoed default values from my db in the textboxes .
I updated the values and pressed the Submit button, but it did not capture the updated value; it still got the default values.

// **EDIT**

Eg. values I have gotten from the db are "email@email.com" for $_email and "91231231" for $_contact.

I changed the email textbox value to "email2@email.com" and clicked the button, but the var_dump($_POST) still shows the original value "email@email.com" instead of the updated one.

//

The form (account_console.php)

```
    <form action="../lib/update_details.php" method="post"> 

         ...
    <span class="form_label">E-mail</span>
    <span class="form_value"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tbEmail2" value="<?  php echo $_email; ?>"  /></span><BR>
    <span class="form_label">Contact No.</span> 
    <span class="form_value"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tbContactNo2"  value="<?php echo $_contact; ?>" /></span><BR>

    <span class="form_label">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="form_value"><input type="submit" name="btnUpdateProfile" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" /></span><BR>

    ...
    </form>
```

Retrieval (../lib/update_details.php)

```
    ...
    else if (isset($_POST["btnUpdateProfile"])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    $email = $_POST["tbEmail2"];
    $contact_no = $_POST["tbContactNo2"];   

    ....
```

var_dump($_POST) returns

```
    array(6) { ["tbEmail2"]=> string(17) "email@email.com" ["tbContactNo2"]=> string(8) "91231231" ["btnUpdateProfile"]=> string(6) "Update" ["tbNewPw2"]=> string(0) "" ["tbRepPw2"]=> string(0) "" ["iFrom"]=> string(30) "../student/account_console.php" }
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: For me it is unclear what your asking? `$email` doesn't have value? Database not updated?

Comment: I notice you are naming the variables `$email` and `$contact_no` in Retrieval but echoing out `_$email` and `_$contact` in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure the updated value is actually being sent using a HTTP proxy inspector like Fiddler or the browser developer tools network inspector.

Or just change the form method="get" and you can see the value in the query-string.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`$_POST['tbEmail2'];`

instead of:

`$_POST["tbEmail2"];`